# Unwanted null in ajax call causes not found error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with ajax requests. Unwanted null
is addded to the request to controller and it causes
not found error in  console as shown below, and variable y is ignored
in concatenation

```
GET http://localhost:8080/results/675305/null 404 (Not Found)
```

but i want a request to look like

```
GET http://localhost:8080/results/675305/edit
```

Code of the ajax call below:

```
 function openEditModal(id){

        var x="/results/";
        var y="/edit";
        console.log(x+id+y);
        $.ajax({
            url: x +id+ y,
            success: function(data){
                $("#editResultModalHolder").html(data);
                $('#editResultModal').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I wrote unwanted null, because when I change content of the
y variable from "/edit" to "/edit/" it leads to THIS request string

```
GET http://localhost:8080/results/675305/edit/null 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Firstly you code can be simplified to ```url: `/results/${id}/edit`,```. That being said, nothing in the example will add the 'null' string to the end of the URL. Check your routing isn't doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function openEditModal(id){
    var url ="/results/id/edit";
    url = url.replace('id', id);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            $("#editResultModalHolder").html(data);
            $('#editResultModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You can try a snippet here

```js
function replaceIdInUrl(id){
    var url ="/results/id/edit";
    url = url.replace('id', id);
    document.write(url);
}
replaceIdInUrl(15);
```